# Adding custom text to oAuth consent screen in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I have created a Google workspace add-on for Google Calendar. This was published as `internal app`. When user are authorizing the add-on, the oAuth consent screen asks them to allow the add-on to `edit their calendar`. This is coming based on the scope defined in the oAuth Consent screen.

I received the feedback from users that this claim from Google is intimidating to them.

I re-visited the oAuth consent screen in the Google Cloud console and at no point I am seeing any option to add any texts.

Is it possible to add some kind of disclaimer as text in the oAuth Consent screen stating that the add-on will not edit/delete any of user's existing calendar bookings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have any control over the text displayed on the consent screen Google controls this.

If you don't want to ask for permission to edit their calendar then use a lower level scope like read only, but if you need to edit their calendars then you have to ask for permission to edit.

You will just need to reassure your users that you are not going to edit existing events.   Google cant control what your doing so they have to tell the users you have access to edit everything.